# Reverse QMetaMethod::fromSignal()

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I already have a working connection from `SomeClass::somSignal` using the `SIGNAL()` macro but I don't have a way of connecting it to a lambda using `&SomeClass::someSignal` mostly because `someClass` is inaccessible. I have the `QObject *`, though.
I tried to look into `QMetaObject`; it should have some sort of look-up structure where these details are kept.

We can have:

```
QMetaMethod::fromSignal(PointerToMemberFunction)
```

returning *QMetaMethod*

My question is, is it possible to have something like this?

```
fromMetaMethod(QMetaMethod)
```

returning *PointerToMemberFunction*
??

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like an xy-problem.  How do you propose to use the value returned from `fromMetaMethod(QMetaMethod)`?

Comment: Hi. `Short answer`, for connecting to that signal.
`Long answer`, pure curiosity. If you can find "by address", each QMetaObject should have some sort of look-up structure where these details are kept.
`Longer answer`, I already have a working connection using the SIGNAL() macro. Just wanted to use a lambda as the slot. But I don't have a way of writing something like &someClass::someSignal mostly because someClass is inaccessible. I have the QObject *, though.

Answer (score 0):

One way to create the connection you want does not require you to find any methods address.
Simply:

1. Create a signal-to-signal connection, from `SomeClass::someSignal` to your own signal in your own class using the `SIGNAL()` connection style.
2. Connect your signal to the lambda.

You only have to make sure the parameters of the original signal are forwarded to your lambda.

Example:

```
QObject::connect(
    pointerToSomeClass, SIGNAL(someSignal(int)),
    pointerToMyClass  , SIGNAL(mySignal(int)),
    Qt::DirectConnection
);
QObject::connect(
    pointerToMyClass, &MyClass::mySignal,
    [](int i) { ... }
);
```

---

If you happen to need the sender of the original signal, then you will need a slot.

Example:

```
void myClass::mySlot(int i)
{
    emit mySignal(sender(), i);
}
```

and

```
QObject::connect(
    pointerToSomeClass, SIGNAL(someSignal(int)),
    pointerToMyClass  , SIGNAL(mySlot(int)),
    Qt::DirectConnection
);
QObject::connect(
    pointerToMyClass, &MyClass::mySignal,
    [](QObject* sender, int i) { ... }
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But as I mentioned, I already have a working connection using `SIGNAL()`. Basically meaning that the problem that originated the question was solved before asking anything. I am just curious if there is some way of getting a pointer to a member function from the QMetaObject itself (to avoid using proxy classes). That's all. But it does not seem possible then.

Comment: @Alvein, Except you have specifically said you want to connect a lambda to it, which you can't do it using the SIGNAL() macro. What I answered is that part of your question specifically (which was not solved before asking anything like you say).

Comment: I commented about the lambda because I was asked more details. But that's not part of the original question ("My question is..."), which is very specific. And I did not say any part of the question was already solved. It's the problem that made me wonder all this. But thanks for the effort in giving me alternatives.